# SharePoint 2010 - Versions Number from Website on SharePointSite

Tags: version-history, footnote

it is possible to show the Versions Number from a SharePoint Site on the Site like a footer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have a user control which display the BuildVersion of the farm, and show this within your MasterPage in the right place.

The BuildVersion property:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spfarm.buildversion.aspx

Creating User Controls for SharePoint:

http://sharepointinsight.blogspot.com/2007/07/web-user-controls-in-sharepoint.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But is there also a no code solution for this problem? like [Version] or something else?

Comment: Nope, I don't think so.

Comment: Yeah, don't think there is. The user control could be dead simple, though - your basic ASCX with something like this in: <% Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.Local.BuildVersion.ToString(); %> - no need for any assemblies, just the ASCX deployed to the CONTROLTEMPLATES directory (although I'm not yet sure how sandboxable this is).

Comment: hmm, you might get trouble with permissions fetching farm properties with a regular user, so remember to test if this work without elevation.

Comment: Good point there, +1